# Cant hide a button?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this button , where i set at the beginning of the program , now if i try to hide it or show it right after i set him it works with:

```
button.hidden=YES; //set yes or no does works ,
```

If i try to do that later, when i click on it, it wouldn't disappear .

```
-(void)outb:(UIButton*)button
{
    NSLog(@"%@",button); //has a pointer
    button.hidden=YES;
   butotnPointer.hidden=YES;
```

does not work .

here is the button :

```
//OUT
self.outb = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
self.outb.contentHorizontalAlignment=UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentCenter;
self.outb.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.4];
[self.outb addTarget:self action:@selector(outb:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIImage *outImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"outButton.png"];
[self.outb setImage:outImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
self.outb.frame=CGRectMake(heart.frame.origin.x-bw, startY+(heart.frame.size.width-bh)/2.0, bw, bh);
self.outb.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[self.view addSubview:self.outb];
```

Comment: Check your pointers. Check is self.outb pointer is same as the one you get on the IBAction, outb:(UIButton*)button. You might actually placing 2 buttons (your init code executed twice) and then you are hiding the top button but still see the one below it

Comment: Check yours init code, in which method does it placed?

Comment: if(button.hidden){ butten.hidden=NO} else {button.hidden=YES}

Comment: Are you using a xib or storyboard?

Comment: Why is your method name `outb:` the same as what I am assuming your button is called `outb` seems a little confusing this, does it not?

Comment: I can confirm this code does work and button is hidden when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you access button by using public (probably) property with

```
self.outb
```

Then you set attributes and finally add button to your view

```
[self.view addSubview:self.outb];
```

If you use IBOutlet, last message is redundant. You don't need to add button as a subview because it has been already added. Delete last stroke and try again.

Hope it helps!